# Django Help: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charfield'

Tags: python, django

I have seen several similar posts of other attributes found but not this. New to Python and Django- I've done the first part of the several tutorials including Django's "Polls" tutorial and when it gets to the point where I syncdb for my app I invariably get 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute CharField.

In models I have copied exactly as the tutorial says:

from django.db import models

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
# Create your models here.
```

'polls' is also added to installed apps and I'm using sqlite3, windows 7, python 2.7.

Any help very appreciated! (I'm trying very hard to learn!)

Answer (score 56):

That is `CharField`, with uppercase 'f', and not `Charfield` as in your code.

Comment: Geez, it's the simplest friggin things staring me right in the face! Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 11):

I think in forms.py you are using

```
from django.forms import forms
```

Please use this

```
from django import forms
```

Answer (score 3):

change `charfield` to:

```
CharField(max_length = 10)
```

both `C` and `F` should be capitalized

Comment: Is there a reason to change the length from `200` to `10`?  It obscures the point you're actually making (typo of `CharField`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
  question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Instead of :

```
  question = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but following code works for me:

```
from django.db import models
#Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default =0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Simply change charfield() to charField() ..

Answer (score 0):

In model `Poll`, spelling of `CharField` is not properly formatted. Ie you have written a small letter `f` inplace of a capital letter `F`. So, replace `Charfield` by `CharField`. You can see the code below:

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published') class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this
`from django.db import models`

Comment: I got this error
 ```AttributeError: module 'django_countries.models' has no attribute 'CharField'```
This work for me ```from django.db import models```